# Display two different values by selecting one dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display two values in two different input boxes. For example, if select 'A',
two input box should display 'a' in first input box and '01' in second input box. But my concept displaying only 'a' & not '01'.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="trying()" onchange="trying2()">
    <option value="" >Select</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="display" id="display" />
<input type="text" name="display2" id="display2" />
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
function trying() {
    document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("test").value;
}

function trying2() {
    if (option.value == "a") {
        document.getElementById("display2").value = 01;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use jQuery, what is _jQuery_ tag doing here?

Comment: your suggestions can be from jquery too.

Comment: you've got 'onChange' in there twice

Comment: you can call `trying2()` from `trying1()` simple....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your select "onchange" like this:

> ```
> <select name="test" id="test" onchange="trying();trying2();">
> <option value="" >Select</option>
> <option value="a">A</option>
> <option value="b">B</option>
> </select>
> ```

And your "trying2" script should look like this:

```
    function trying2() {
        if (document.getElementById("test").value == "a") {
            document.getElementById("display2").value = 01;
        }
    }
```

And if you would like to use JQuery then you can do it like this, (remember to remove  onchange="trying();trying2();") :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').on('change', function () {

            var myVal = $('#test').val();
            $('#display').val(myVal);
            if (myVal == 'a') { $('#display2').val(myVal); }
            else { $('#display2').val(''); }

        });
    });
```

Comment: check the update .. make sure you tweak your "trying2" script

Comment: Let's just say that usage of inline JavaScript is discouraged nowdays.

Answer (score 1):

Merge those 2 functions into one like below:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("test");    
function trying() {
  var selectVal = selector.value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = selectVal;
  document.getElementById("display2").value = selectVal == "a" ? "01" : "";
}

selector.addEventListener("change", trying);
```

**Demo [on codepen](http://codepen.io/lshettyl/pen/GgZEpV)**

P.S. inline event handlers are not encouraged unless there is no other way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two attributes of the same name (onchange), only one is applying. You could do a few things

- Call both functions from a single `onchange` attribute
- Use `addEventListener` to add multiple handlers
- `$('#test').on('change', trying).on('change', trying2)`

The second problem is

```
function trying2() {
    // "option" is not defined
    if (option.value == "a") {
        document.getElementById("display2").value = 01;
    }
}
```

Should be

```
function trying2() {
    if (document.getElementById("test").value == "a") {
        document.getElementById("display2").value = 01;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you do it like this:

```
<input id"abc"/>
<input id"cde"/>
```

and then with jquery:

```
$("#abc").val("a");
$("#cde").val("01");
```